# SQLite in universal app with dynamic data model

Tags: c#, sqlite, win-universal-app

I'm having a problem with SQLite in universal app. I don't know data model in advance, actually it is fully dynamic based on the data received from the server. SQLite for universal apps uses ORM and that's the problem. I can easily generate SQL queries to create tables and CRUD operations and execute them except SELECT.
SQLite has the following method:

```
public Task<List<T>> QueryAsync<T> (string sql, params object[] args)
```

I don't know type T. I tried to use dynamic type and create my own type based on dynamic, but it didn't work. The best would be something like SqlDataReader from ADO.NET, but I couldn't find anything like this.